# Not receive refresh_token from OAuth 2 Server Laravel

Tags: php, oauth, laravel, laravel-4, oauth-2.0

I'm currently using OAuth 2 Server Laravel from [here](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel)

I'm using both  `client_credentials` and `refresh_token`  as `grant_types` .

```
'grant_types' => array(

        'client_credentials' => array(
            'class'                 => 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\ClientCredentials',
            'access_token_ttl'      => 60,
        ),

        'refresh_token' => array(
            'class'                 => 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\RefreshToken',
            'access_token_ttl'      => 3600,
            'refresh_token_ttl'     => 604800,
            'rotate_refresh_tokens' => false,
        ),
    ),
```

When I'm requesting token from AuthorizationServer, I only receive this response:

```
{
    "access_token": "0JpNT0vORf4HC2fTfvkssjS3SEPhfai2YRTgELIC",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires": 1395127143,
    "expires_in": 60
}
```

As you can see no `refresh_token` return in response, only `access_token`. How to solve this? How to get `refresh_token` ?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand the Client Credentials Grant is unable to return a refresh token, refer to [section 4.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3) of the spec where it talks about the response for this particular grant.

You'll need to use a different grant type if you require a refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Set `rotate_refresh_tokens`to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The refresh token grant is to be used together with one other of the following grants: `PasswordGrant`, `AuthCodeGrant`.